# Getting a struct variable to show in the UITableView Cell? swift /xcode8

Tags: swift, struct, xcode8

Im trying to get my struct variable, "title" to display as the cell text label in the UITableView, does anyone know if this is possible?

I have achieved this before using a string, but I'm not sure how to access one of the struct variables in this context

This is where I have declared the struct

```
import Foundation

struct Note {
   var title: String
   var text: String

}

class Notes {

    var notes:[Note]

    public static let sharedInstance = Notes()

    private init() {
        self.notes = []
    }

    public func add(title1: String, text1: String) throws {
        self.notes.append(Note(title: title1, text: text1))

    }
}
```

and this is the controller class, where I am trying to add simple values to the struct and display the value of the "title" variable in the struct

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "note1", for: indexPath)

        let note1 = Notes.sharedInstance
        try? note1.add(title1: "Hello", text1: "World")
        print(note1)

       if let label = cell.textLabel {
        // I've been trying to get it to work on this line
        //label.text = note1.notes(get title here?)[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close!  You need to pick out the array element before trying to get its title:

```
if let label = cell.textLabel {
    label.text = note1.notes[indexPath.row].title
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

struct Note {
    var title: String
    var text: String

    init(title: String, text: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
    }

}

class Notes {

    var notes:[Note] = []
    public static let sharedInstance = Notes()

    private init() {
     self.notes = []
    }

    public func add(title1: String, text1: String) throws {
      notes.append(Note(title: title1, text: text1))
   }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

     var note1 = Notes.sharedInstance

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for i in 1...10 {
          try! note1.add(title1: "dfsad \(i)", text1: "sdfsdfsd")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return note1.notes.count
   }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell
      cell.textLabel?.text = note1.notes[indexPath.row].title
      return cell
}

}
```

OutPut:

[image]
Thanks:)